QGIS – Add columns (number and names) based on the content of another column
Is it possible in QGIS to create new columns based on the values from a concatenated field within the same table?
For example, I have a table with data that looks like this:

I would like to add a specified number of columns based on the information contained in the "Sector" column. In this case, QGIS would automatically create 3 new columns, which I can then update as needed. The result would look like this:

A bit like a pivot table!
For this project, I’m working with expressions and algorithms in the Graphical Modeler. I’m looking for a solution that would work within this context.

The number can vary, cannot know in advance. The name isn't always sector too.

Ok, otherwise you could have used SQL, example

Since this includes removing features from your data, I think you need to create a new output file and can't work within the same table.

I’m considering adding a specific column to organize data by "Sectors" with no other possible values. Then, I plan to create 50 columns named "Sector 1" to "Sector 50" and populate them with the refactored data.
Afterward, I can delete any empty columns. The only issue is that I might not be able to name the columns exactly as I want. I might be able to use the "Rename Field" function to achieve this. I need tot ry.

You can't name dBase fields with a space in them. It might not be permitted to add fifty fields if the record width would exceed the 4000 byte limit. There's also a limit of 100 fields per record in the spec, though 255 is enforced. The proper way to model this relationally is in a one-to-many ancillary table.

Here’s how I approached this problem. Although it’s not the cleanest method, several constraints led me to this solution:

I don’t know how to program in Python.

The expected results are more about data rendering than data analysis. This would be straightforward in Excel but is challenging
in QGIS, which is not designed primarily for this purpose.

The tool must be simple and integrated into QGIS for other users. Manual script execution or requiring additional software is not an option.


I worked with QGIS Model Builder and used the following steps. I have two layers:
- ZONES_ETUDE_POLY (ZHP): Represents the study zones.
- ESPECES_PT (EP): Contains species points.

Steps

1. Numbered Sectors in ZHP

I assigned a unique identifier to each sector in the ZHP layer:
Sect_Class =
'SectionFilter ' || to_string(@row_number)


2. Intersection to Transfer Data
I used the Intersection algorithm to transfer information from ZHP to EP. Later, I may use overlay_contains.
3. Calculated Individuals per Category
For each sector, I calculated the total number of individuals per category using this expression:
"AggregSect" =
    IF(
        aggregate(@layer, 'sum', "effectif_p", filter:="Sect_Class" = 'SectionFilter 1' AND "nom_simple" = attribute(@parent, 'nom_simple')) > 0,
        'SectionFilter 1 ' || to_string(aggregate(@layer, 'sum', "effectif_p", filter:="Sect_Class" = 'SectionFilter 1' AND "nom_simple" = attribute(@parent, 'nom_simple'))) || '@',
        ''
    )
) ||
    IF(
    aggregate(@layer, 'sum', "effectif_p", filter:="Sect_Class" = 'SectionFilter 2' AND "nom_simple" = attribute(@parent, 'nom_simple')) > 0,
    'SectionFilter 2 ' || to_string(aggregate(@layer, 'sum', "effectif_p", filter:="Sect_Class" = 'SectionFilter 2' AND "nom_simple" = attribute(@parent, 'nom_simple'))) || '@',
    ''
)

This pattern was repeated for all 20 sectors.
**Issue**: The expression is repetitive because I couldn’t find a better way to avoid specifying each 'SectionFilter x' manually.

4. Refactored Fields
I created 20 new fields (one per sector) using an expression like this:
"SectionFilter 1" = 
Coalesce(
    Nullif(
        Nullif(
            Replace(
                With_variable('P', 
                    IF(stat_eff = 'Valeur approximative', '~', ''), 
                    @P || regexp_substr("AggregSect", 'SectionFilter 1 (.*?)@')
                ),
            '~0', '0'),
        '~') || ' ind.', 
    ' ind.')
, '-')

This was applied to each sector individually (changind 'SectionFilter x').
5. Regrouped Data
I used the regrouping algorithm to aggregate the required fields.
6. Renamed Fields
To rename fields with meaningful names, I used the Rename Field algorithm with an expression for each field:
Rename "SectionFilter 1" =
attribute(get_feature(@Classement_secteurs_OUTPUT, 'Sect_Class', 'SectionFilter 1'), 'nom')

The "nom" field contains the names of the sections (e.g., Section 1, Section 2, Section 3).
This process matches each "SectionFilter x" with its corresponding name, if available.
7. Deleted Unnecessary Fields
I deleted all unnecessary fields using the Delete Fields algorithm:
Array(,'nom','SectionFilter 1','SectionFilter 2','SectionFilter 3','SectionFilter 4','SectionFilter 5','SectionFilter 6','SectionFilter 7','SectionFilter 8','SectionFilter 9','SectionFilter 10','SectionFilter 11','SectionFilter 12','SectionFilter 13','SectionFilter 14','SectionFilter 15','SectionFilter 16','SectionFilter 17','SectionFilter 18','SectionFilter 19','SectionFilter 20')

Only the "renamed fields" were kept, and the remaining fields were deleted because they were no longer needed.

This workflow is effective but somewhat slow (approximately 20 seconds for 450 entities).
I’d like to find a more efficient way to calculat the field AggregSect without manually specifying each 'SectionFilter x'.
It would be great to rename all fields in a single step, but the current setup doesn’t allow this within the same algorithm.

There is a problem if I reach the limit of 20 sections, I might have to add 50 more to be safe. But I might reach another size limit as mentioned by Vince. Will try it layer.

This solution doesn't apply if I want to organize per dates. Which I also need sometimes... I can eventually find a way to organize per year, but I don't see any way to organize per dates.

Also, there is an issue with the names of columns. 'SectionFilter X' = 15 characters.
So, 20*15 = 300char ; which is more than the field limit. Better to use another column name (like SFx) ; and also better to round summed values in order to also reduce the size of the strings. With these changes, it is working so far.
